# .Select with EF Core returns ModelError in View

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to present a list of appointments together with their respective participants and/or subjects.

The Planner model is as follows:

```
public class Planner : BaseEntity
{        
    public int? ProjectCandId { get; set; }
    public int? CandidateId { get; set; }        
    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }        

    public DateTime PlanDatum { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }        
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Candidate Candidate { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectCand ProjectCand { get; set; }
}
```

I only require a select number of fields from Customer, Project, and Candidate, so I created a controller which looks like:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
       var afspraken = await _context.Planner
            .Include(c => c.Customer)
            .Include(c => c.Project)
            .Include(c => c.Candidate)
            .Select(s => new { s.Id, s.CandidateId, s.CustomerId, s.Description,  s.IsDeleted, s.Location, s.PlanDatum, 
                s.Customer.CompanyName, 
                s.Project.ProjectTitle, 
                s.Candidate.FullName })
            .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return View(afspraken);
    }
```

I use in my view `@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Planner>`.

When NOT applying the .Select-line in the controller everything works just fine, but with it, it generates the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType7`10[System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.String,System.Boolean,System.String,System.DateTime,System.String,System.String,System.String]]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BeagleNoseV3.Models.Planner]'.

I have tried to create a ViewModel, but that complicated things only more. I would like to use the .Select to create a more efficient query, but I am stuck.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT ViewModel Scenario**

I have tried the ViewModel-approach, but there I struggled on how to link the VModel to the Class.

I created `PlannerVM` and `PlanVMList`:

```
public class PlannerVM : BaseEntityVM  //BaseEntityVM provides Id, IsDeleted and some other administrative elements
{
    public int? ProjectCandId { get; set; }
    public int? CandidateId { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

    public DateTime PlanDatum { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }        
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CandidateFullName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class PlanVMList
{
    public List<PlannerVM> AppointList { get; set; }
}
```

I fail to come up with the right code in the PlannerController to link the ViewModel to my dataset `afspraken`. Any thoughts?

Comment: View model is the way to go. How did that "complicate things only more"?

Comment: I am struggling to get the ViewModel Approach to work. I will add an EDIT section to my question to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Your **afspraken** is List of Anonymous and you are passing it to View, which expects model type of `IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Planner>`

Change your final Select statement to something like:

```
.Select(s => new MyProject.Models.Planner {
...
})
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, but Planner is not an IEnumerable, so that did not work. I then created a List<Planner> PlanList and used that in the .Select statement, but that did not work either. The message is that I PlanList is 'a variable, but used as a type',

Answer (score 0):

From your requirement,to display `Planner` together with their respective participants and/or subjects.No need to specify the `.Select`.

Here is a working demo like below:

1.Model:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
public class Planner : BaseEntity
{
    public int? ProjectCandId { get; set; }
    public int? CandidateId { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

    public DateTime PlanDatum { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Candidate Candidate { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}  
public class Customer: BaseEntity
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
public class Candidate: BaseEntity
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
public class Project: BaseEntity
{
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
}
```

2.View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Planner>
<h1>Index</h1>
<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CandidateId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PlanDatum)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Candidate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Project)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsDeleted)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CandidateId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlanDatum)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer.CompanyName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Candidate.FullName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project.ProjectTitle)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsDeleted)
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

3.Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var model = _context.Planner.Include(p => p.Candidate).Include(p => p.Customer).Include(p => p.Project);
    return View(await model.ToListAsync());
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I am a little confused however. I already have classes for Customer,Candidate and Project and I include them through the `public virtual Customer Customer {get; set;} etc.` I cannot again redefine them. The whole purpose is to extract a single element from that class, as not to bloat the query.

Comment: What do you mean for `redefine them`?You just need to search for the object and include the child elements like what you did in the backend.And select single element you want in the view.

Comment: Hi,DId you still have problems now?

Comment: sorry to have not come back to you. I gave up. The query works fine, if I do noit use the .Select and extract the full entity. I guess the core of the issue (apart form my programming skills) is how to extend a List and then use it in a View. Thanks for helping me though.